# Infinite quon statistics/Quantum Boltzmann statistics: models and hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, second-quantization, spin-statistics

I learned long ago that there are some exotic classes of statistics. One of them is called $q$-on or quon statistics. It is given by

$$a_ia^+_j-qa^+_ja_i=\delta_{ij}$$

Infinite statistics (Quantum Boltzmann statistics or Cuntz algebra) is the particular case of quon statistics with $q=0$.

Question: is there some physical model resembling $q$-statistics or quons? What is the Hamiltonian for such a thing? Is there some relativistic field theory model for that thing?

Comment: See this [paper](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0103-97332003000200004&script=sci_arttext)

Comment: What about the q=0 case, Trimok? The Hamiltonian for q=0 seems to be ill-defined...