# What is a quon?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, quasiparticles

I have sometimes seen the term 'quon' in quantum physics and I a not sure what does it mean. Most of the time I see it as a synonym of quasi-particle but sometimes in questions like this one: [Infinite quon statistics/Quantum Boltzmann statistics: models and hamiltonians](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74376/infinite-quon-statistics-quantum-boltzmann-statistics-models-and-hamiltonians) there are some imposed statistics. Wikipedia disambiguation defines it as a quantum object according to this book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Reality. Is the term different from quasi-particle? Does it have a unique definition?

Comment: found this https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02630  "A quon is a composite that acts as a particle. Specifically a quon is a hemisphere containing a neutral pair of open strings with opposite charge."

Comment: @annav the question is, is the definition in a single article a good representation of the definition used in the rest of the articles?

Answer (score -2):

I think that *quon* is just an outdated fashion for meaning the quantized particle in a field. (i.e, the quon of the electromagnetic field is the photon)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).